# GWT, Firefox and Windows 7 Touch

Tags: firefox, gwt, windows-7

i am trying to set up an application with GWT. The problem is that Firefox and GWT not handling Windows 7 touch gestures properly. When using Firefox on an sample GWT page i am not able to do everytime touch gestures handled by Windows. Normally Windows 7 converts those touch gesture into keyboard shortcuts, but with Firefox they work like 20% of the time...

With Chrome and IE 9 there are no problems.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Update: With Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79m it does not work as well. On all pages, not only GWT sites...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this answer and below comments may help on clarifying various issues related to the problems above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942720/1915920